# Stripe PHP - how to create token with existing customer/card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've seen many similar posts, but cannot find one that answers my question. I am able to retrieve an existing customer and their cards, but cannot figure out how to create a token using this. All the examples I find require card info (e.g. card number cvv etc...), which if you retrieve a card through the API I don't have access to. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);
$card = $customer->sources->retrieve($card_id);

$token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
      "card" => // What to put here???
    )
  );
```

Comment: There is no need to create token for existing customer which having cards added. All you need to set the `source` as existing card `id` for a customer if the customer having multiple cards.

Comment: Why you need `token`?? you are already having `customer_id` !!!

Answer (score -1):

As @zico explained in a comment, you don't need to create new tokens once you've saved the card with a customer object. You can simply pass the customer's ID in the `customer` parameter, and optionally the card's ID in the `source` parameter (if the customer has multiple cards and you want to charge a non-default card).

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 400,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => "cus_...", // ID of the customer you want to charge
    "source" => "card_...", // ID of the specific card, only needed if the customer has
                            // multiple cards and you want to charge a different
                            // card than the default one
));
```